# commerce unique identification number for each item on each transaction

Tags: commerce, entities

What options are they to achieve a unique identification number for each item sold in a commerce store.

I want to have a unique number for each item on each transaction, the number needs to be unique across all transactions.

even if I have 5 of the same line item in an order I should still get 5 unique numbers.

I have a unique id number per item per order but i don't know how to achieve a truly unique id.
Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

prepend your unique id with the order number. Since it's already unique within the order, and presuming an order number is unique, [order-number]-[unique-id] should return a truly unique value with the added benefit of being traceable since the order number would have a searchable or reference-able value.

EDIT:

Further research yielded the module [Field default token](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_default_token)

```
This module enables to use tokens as field default values.
```

Using this you should be able to create the order-ID combination (or any other combination). To prevent user tinkering, I would also suggest Field Permissions:

```
The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions 
to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
```

Comment: Their is an option in store=>products sku that will provide you to add unique id for each product sold or listed

Comment: I believe op wants a unique number for each item on each transaction, not a unique item number as they indicate they already produce a unique id per transaction, but that number isn't necessarily unique across multiple transactions

Comment: @Geoff Yes thats exactly it. I would like to have a unique number for each item on each transaction that's unique across all orders

Comment: see my edit....

Comment: @Geoff ok so if i understand that correctly after adding a field to the line item and specify the correct token, each time an item is added to an order it should have a unique id.

Comment: it should, assuming the order number is unique, and the id is unique within that order...

Answer (score 0):

There a two main options there:

1. Order ID
2. Line Item ID

The Order ID is unique across all orders.

The Line Item ID is per-line item on the order and is also unique across all orders. Each line item on an order has a unique Line Item ID.